# How to pass argument from iframe to parent?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a situation where iframe triggers click event for parent window and passes argument to the parent. I have tried below code but the argument is undefined. Don't know what am I doing wrong.

Code in iframe

```
jQuery("#add",window.parent.document).trigger('click',"3");
```

Code in parent window-

```
jQuery("#add").live('click',function(e,cid){                    
    //cid is undefined
});
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applicable only if iframe src is from same domain as parent.

parent window

```
jQuery("#add").live('click',function(e,cid){                    
    //cid is undefined
});
window.eventFromIframe = function(id, eventName value){
   jQuery("#"+id).trigger('click',value); 
};
```

inside iframe

```
window.parent.eventFromIframe('add','click', 3);
```

Comment: Hi @Anoop, inside iframe, what is "eventFromIframe" ? Is it a function in iframe?